# Yearly Interest on house and deposit

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Suppose you currently have $50,000 deposited into a bank account and the account pays you a constant interest rate of 3.5% per year on your deposit. You are planning to buy a house with the current price of $300,000. The price will increase by 1.5% per year. It still requires a minimum down payment of 20% of the house price.

Write a while loop to calculate how many (integer) years you need to wait until you can afford the down payment to buy the house.

```
m = 50000 #money you have
i = 0.035 #interest rate
h = 300000 #house price
f = 0.015 #amount house will increase by per year
d= 0.2 #percent of down payment on house
y = 0 #number of years
x = 0 #money for the down payment

mn = h*d #amount of down payment

while m <= mn:
   m = (m+(m*i)) #money you have plus money you have times interest
   y = y + 1 #year plus one
   mn = mn +(h*f*y)

print(int(y))
```

The answer you should get is 10.

I keep getting the wrong answer, but I am not sure what is incorrect.

Comment: Think about how you are calculating the value of the house. When you calculated the interest on your savings you used the previous year's value and added the interest to that. Try rewriting the mn line so it looks more like the m line.

Comment: It worked! Thank you.```while m <= mn:
   m = (m+(m*i)) #money you have plus money you have times interest
   y = y + 1 #year plus one
   mn = mn +(mn*f)```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the code by using the compound interest formula.

```py
def compound_interest(amount, rate, years):
    return amount * (rate + 1) ** years


while compound_interest(m, i, y) < d * compound_interest(h, f, y):
    y += 1
```

---

If you are allowed to do without the while loop, you can resolve the inequality after the years `y`.

> [image]

So you get this code snippet:

```py
import math

base = (i + 1) / (f + 1)
arg = (d * h) / m
y = math.ceil(math.log(arg, base))
```